# Div contents overflowing from margins

Tags: html, css

The css involved is:

```
#menudiv{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#404040;
}

#menulist{
    list-style-type:square;
    list-style-position:outside;
    font-size:16px;
}

#contentdiv{
    font-family:verdana;
}

p{
    font-family:verdana;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:20px;
    font-size:12pt;
}
```

and the html involved is:

```
<div id="menudiv">
    <img class="titleico" src="../images/code.png" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; Dev<br />
    <ul id="menulist">
        <li><a href="yo">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentdiv">
   <p>Some paragraphs go here</p>
</div>

<!-- the last 3 items belong to footer div which has no style-->
```

As you can see in the image attached below, the contents of #contentdiv are overflowing from their margins and it looks like the div spreads over to new territory (under the #menudiv). How can I stop this from happening?

[image]

After applying the edit suggested by fauxserious this is the result (note that I added a border for #menudiv to see what's going on)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/cotzxqqq/)

The key to getting this is to use a fluid layout. Changing all of your width, left/right padding, and left/right margins to use percents should do the trick. Also they should add up to 100%.

### Remove this CSS

```
width:20%;
padding-right:3px;
```

### Replace with

```
width: 19%;
padding-right: 1%;
```

Also you'll need to add `float: right` to your CSS for `#contentdiv`

Comment: Flawless! I now understood the problem. I had the width of #menudiv set to 20% and then there was an added width of the padding too. Putting #menudiv's width to 19% and padding to 1% makes the total to be 20%. And yes, I added a float-right to my content div.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Really the better way to go if you are going to do something like that is to have a container with left margin or padding that the menu floats in then ALL other content is outside of the menu area.

Something like this:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 150px;">
    <div class="menu" style="margin-left:-150px">My Menu</div>
    <div class="content">
        All the other content goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

It might not be "responsive" but if you don't care it always works.

Comment: I do want it to be responsive, but +1 for the unique approach to the matter!

Comment: Well your approach will always require a heigh of some kind on the menu to keep content out of it's column. If you want something that is responsive you will need some kind of framework that supports "Columns".

Answer (score 1):

The menu's height isn't filling the entire height of the body so the content is allowed to fall below it.  If you added a border around the menu, you'd see what was happening.  Good news is that this is an easy fix because your menu is a percentage.

```
#contentdiv{
    font-family:verdana;
    width:80%; 
}
```

Comment: Unless #contentdiv is floated the content is still gonna fall under the #menudiv. Also because thay have a 3px padding-right on #menudiv we cant have 20% for the menu and 80% for the content.

Comment: This further worsens the situation. Please refer to the 2nd image I posted in my question statement to see what I mean.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the additional widths from the padding, that percentage wont work correctly then.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your padding-right to be a margin with a % instead of px value. Then float your content div and give it a width.

```
#menudiv{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:5%;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#404040;
}

#contentdiv{
    font-family:verdana;
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
```

check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joncampbell/h3u5otr7/%20jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid floats altogether and use [CSS table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout). This allows you to define the nav width and have the content fill the remainder of the space. You can also change the width (maybe with a media-query) without it breaking the layout.

Use `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid having to include the elements' padding in your calculations.

```css
body * {box-sizing:border-box} /* make paddings INCLUDED in the box sizing */
#menudiv{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    min-width:150px; /* maybe add a minimum width so that the menu doesnt get too small on narrow viewports */
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    /*float:left;
    height:100%; < remove these */
    display:table-cell; /* make table-cell */
    vertical-align:top; /* align content to top */
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#404040;
}

#menulist{
    list-style-type:square;
    list-style-position:outside;
    font-size:16px;
}

#contentdiv{
    font-family:verdana;  
    display:table-cell; /* make table-cell */
    vertical-align:top; /* align content to top */  
}

p{
    font-family:verdana;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:20px;
    font-size:12pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="menudiv">
    <img class="titleico" src="../images/code.png" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; Dev<br />
    <ul id="menulist">
        <li><a href="yo">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- 
No whitespace here. it can cause problems if you use inline-block
--><div id="contentdiv">
   <p>Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here</p>
<p>Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here Some paragraphs go here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already got a working (if not technically the smartest) solution to my problem but ... wow and +1 @ your effort in reply to solving my issue. I would probably use this approach in my next web dev projects!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `overflow:auto;` to the content div. So you dont need to specify a fixed width for the content.

```css
#menudiv{
position:relative;
width:20%;
padding-right:3px;
padding-bottom:0px;
float:left;
height:100%;
font-family:ubuntu;
font-size:25px;
color:#404040;
}

#menulist{
list-style-type:square;
list-style-position:outside;
font-size:16px;
}

#contentdiv{
font-family:verdana;
overflow: auto;
}

p{
font-family:verdana;
text-align:justify;
text-indent:20px;
font-size:12pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="menudiv">
<img class="titleico" src="../images/code.png" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; Dev<br />
<ul id="menulist">
    <li><a href="yo">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="contentdiv">
   <p>Some paragraphs go here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores nam, cum illum. Illo amet voluptates sunt inventore est exercitationem at similique quasi nisi. Ad, laboriosam dicta nulla ipsum consequuntur illo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente accusamus ut odio maxime hic voluptatem fugit quibusdam veritatis, maiores recusandae aliquid! Asperiores deleniti harum recusandae iusto, libero laboriosam praesentium repudiandae..</p>
</div>
```